# Find value in other process

Tags: c#, memory, process

I'm trying to find a specific value (byte array or int32) somewhere in the memory of another process. 
The following code returns no results, but other memory scanners (for example cheat engine) can find values.

```
public void CheckForValue()
{
    Process[] proc2 = Process.GetProcessesByName("xxxxxxxxx");
    handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_WM_READ, false, proc2[0].Id); 

    byte[] tofind = new byte[] { 0x01, 0x10, 0x00, 0x01 };
    int results = 0;
    uint PTR = 0x000000;
    int read = 0;
    byte[] page = new byte[4096];
    bool found = false;
    while (PTR <= 0x7FFFFFFF && !found)  
    {
        read = 0;
        page = new byte[4096];
        if (ReadProcessMemory(proc2[0].Handle, (IntPtr)PTR, page, 4096, out read) != false)
        {
            if (ContainsBytes(page, tofind))
            {
                results++;
            }
        }

        PTR += 4096;
    }
}

public bool ContainsBytes(byte[] all, byte[] tofind)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < all.Length - tofind.Length + 1; i++)
    {
        if (all[i] == tofind[0])
        {
            bool found = true;
            for (int a = 1; a < tofind.Length && found; a++)
            {
                if (all[i + a] != tofind[a])
                    found = false;
            }

            if (found)
                return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Edit: was only checking modules before, but not anymore (I think).

Edit 2: I'm getting completely different results than cheat engine. I've tried looking at the values at the exact address, but they are different:

```
ReadProcessMemory(proc2[0].Handle, (IntPtr)0x14F00420, page, 4096, out read);
Log(page[0] + " - " + page[1] + " - " + page[2] + " - " + page[3]);
```

I guess I'm still reading from the wrong memory parts?

Comment: Change all pointer arithmetic to IntPtr. Your code will fail on 64 bit.

Comment: Also, you are just searching modules (loaded DLLs). You aren't searching any dynamically allocated data. Are you aware of that?

Comment: Your code also will miss values if they happen to span a page boundary. Since you are looking a match of 4 bytes, this won't be a problem if the underlying value guaranteed to be aligned on a 4-byte value.

Comment: Thanks, I thought the data would be in a module as well. I've changed my code, but still no results.

Comment: Please confirm that you are targeting a 32 bit process. Also, add error detection. ReadPMem might just fail and you'll never now. At the moment you are just ignoring errors which is always wrong.